# Figuring cases in which this algorithm for finding unique occurrences in array is failing

Tags: c#, algorithm, debugging, testing

I have to do a Codility algorithm test and I picked a question in order to train, however, I can't figure why my algorithm is failing.

Please note that after the fail I did some research and obviously just XORing all values is a better solution, but it only applies to elements that are bitwise operable (with matching behavior), so I'm interested in fixing my solution instead.

Here's the link to the failed test: https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingD7WDBD-JGP/

Basically, you have to find a number that occurs only once in an array where all other numbers occur more than once. Here's my commented solution:
(C# but shouldn't matter much)

```
static public int solution(int[] A)
{
    // the test guarantees non-empty input and odd length
    if (A.Length <= 2) // ofc we could check for == 1 and throw on == 2
        return A[0];

    Array.Sort(A);

    if (A[0] != A[1]) // if 1st element is different than 2nd it's unique
        return A[0];

    for (int i = 2; i < A.Length; i++)
    {
        var previous = A[i-2];
        var current = A[i-1];
        var next = A[i];

        // we process 3 elements at a time, if they are all different
        // the middle one is the unique... we don't test the last
        if (previous != current && current != next)
            return current;
    }

    // we don't test the last element, so if we drop out of the loop
    // it must be the unique element... we could check that and throw
    // if it's not unique but the test description says that won't happen
    return A[A.Length-1];
}
```

That code however is failing some tests, but I can't figure what are these fail cases, here's a SSCCE I'm running locally and all the tests there are apparently fine:
https://gist.github.com/Alan-FGR/d65e55c9aebca4c48c5d69615d105cdb

So, can you guys help me figure what inputs are not being handled correctly? The Codility results don't have that information, just that a few inputs failed (small1, medium2, big1). Thank you!

Comment: You could try a different algorithm, comparing non-overlapping pairs rather than triples.

Comment: @rossum that's true, both a brute force (adding travelled elements to a list and removing when a duplicate is found) and the mentioned XOR aggregation work. However, I really would like to figure the "bug" in that code above.

Comment: With two algorithms you can compare how they work on an input where one of the algorithms fails.

Comment: @rossum the problem is in all tests I could come up with my algorithm works, that's basically my question here: what are the inputs for which my test will fail

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot that the odd element CAN occur more than once, it just have to be odd number of times for your test to fail. As you can see in my example here:

```
using System;

public class main {
  public static void Main(string[] args) {
    int[] failExample= {2,2,2,3,3};
    Console.WriteLine(solution(failExample));
  }
  static public int solution(int[] A) {
    // the test guarantees non-empty input and odd length
    if (A.Length <= 2) // ofc we could check for == 1 and throw on == 2
      return A[0];

    Array.Sort(A);

    if (A[0] != A[1]) // if 1st element is different than 2nd it's unique
      return A[0];

    for (int i = 2; i < A.Length; i++) {
      var previous = A[i - 2];
      var current = A[i - 1];
      var next = A[i];

      // we process 3 elements at a time, if they are all different
      // the middle one is the unique... we don't test the last
      if (previous != current && current != next)
        return current;
    }

    // we don't test the last element, so if we drop out of the loop
    // it must be the unique element... we could check that and throw
    // if it's not unique but the test description says that won't happen
    return A[A.Length - 1];
  }
}
```

Probably you didn't take that in account